# Will I have a problem travelling to USA with a month old Iraqi visa?

Tags: visas, usa, passports, iraq

I plan to travel to America a month after I've travelled to Iraq .... will this cause me a problem on arrival in America?

Comment: Are you travelling with an Iraqi passport or do you have an Iraq stamp in your passport?

Answer (score 10):

With the passage of the [Visa Waiver Program Improvement and Terrorist Travel Prevention Act](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/visa-waiver-program/visa-waiver-program-improvement-and-terrorist-travel-prevention-act-faq) in December 2015, previously-eligible nationals of Visa Waiver Program countries may no longer travel to the U.S. under the VWP if they have been to Iraq, Syria, Iran or Sudan since 2011.  Assuming you are not already a U.S. citizen or permanent resident or a Canadian, you'll need to get a visa.